# JBoss and log4j extras

Tags: jboss, log4j, classpath, jboss5.x

I want to use [log4j extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/) with JBoss 5.1.0.GA.
On my local server I put the jar in `JBOSS_HOME/common/lib` and it works.
On the integration server, I did the same, but I read the following error:

> log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 20 and column 76
>   log4j:WARN Element type "rollingPolicy" must be declared. 
>   log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 22 and column 40
>   log4j:WARN The content of element type "rollingPolicy" must match "EMPTY".  Children of type "comment" are not allowed.

If I move the extras jar in `JBOSS_HOME/server/<profile>/lib` the error disappears, and the logging works as expected (as it does on my machine).

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? What part of the **JBoss configuration** is responsible of the different behaviour?

**EDIT**
I also did a diff between the conf dir on my machine and on the remote server, and the directories are identical.